# Optimizing quality of the output graphs in the pyplot.subplot environment

Tags: python, graphics

I am trying to create multiple bar charts using the `matplotlib.pyplot.subplot` command:

Here's my code:

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for j in range(8):

   y_range = []

   for p in range(5):

       y_range.append(np.random.uniform(0,1))

   x_range = range(len(y_range))

   plt.subplot(8/2, 4, j+1)

   plt.bar(x_range,y_range,align='center')

   x_labels = ["1/2", "1/4", "1/8", "1/16", "1/32"]
   plt.xticks(x_range, x_labels)
   plt.xlabel('Lower Bound')

   plt.ylim([0,1])
   plt.ylabel('Proportion')

plt.show
```

The output is:

[image]

Each graph is quite small in size, and all the graphs are cramped together. Also, the labels for the x-axes and y-axes overlap with the plots, and the ticks on the x-axes also overlap with each other.

Any suggestions on how to improve the quality of the output?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for j in range(8):

   y_range = []

   for p in range(5):

       y_range.append(np.random.uniform(0,1))

   x_range = range(len(y_range))

   plt.subplot(8/2, 4, j+1)

   plt.bar(x_range,y_range,align='center')

   x_labels = ["1/2", "1/4", "1/8", "1/16", "1/32"]
   plt.xticks(x_range, x_labels, rotation='vertical')
   plt.xlabel('Lower Bound')

   plt.ylim([0,1])
   plt.ylabel('Proportion')
plt.tight_layout()
```

! [image]

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at the `figsize` option for more details.

Comment: look at **plt.tight_layout()**  too